# Adding a rewrite rule to page that has no fixed variables and pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

Ive set up a page that users can search posts by tags, four categories, for example.
By Room - By Style - By Colour - By Feature, each has an undefined number of sub categories, depending on how many tags are associated with each category (these categories and sub categories are hard coded)
Works fine, and I have a rewrite rule of:

```
 add_rewrite_rule('discover/interiors/interior-results/(.+)', 'index.php?pagename=discover/interiors/interior-results&tag1=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

I've done it this way as I dont know how many variables a user will select, so it could be:

```
 discover/interiors/interior-results/bedroom/
 discover/interiors/interior-results/bedroom/hotel-chic
 discover/interiors/interior-results/bedroom/hotel-chic/white
```

etc...

As I said, this works fine, but am finding now that as the number of posts increase, I tried adding pagination, which after a lot of head scratching on why its not working, realised that now the pagination is being read by the rewrite rule as a tag (/page/2/)

Is it possible to create a rewrite rule to read x number of variables then the last being the pagination?

**EDIT** Before posting and after writing, I saw other post on here similar, where for them, the rewrite rule of:

```
 add_rewrite_rule('discover/interiors/interior-results/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$', 'index.php?pagename=discover/interiors/interior-results&tag1=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

Worked for them and I can sort of see where they were going, but unfortunately, this breaks the first page (404) and the page/2 is actually contents of page 1 so..
If anyone can guide me in the right direction and as always any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work, changing the regex from (.+) to (.*)

Maybe helpful for others searching same rewrite on search and pagination.

```
 add_rewrite_rule('discover/interiors/interior-results/(.*)/page/([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?pagename=discover/interiors/interior-results&tag1=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
 add_rewrite_rule('discover/interiors/interior-results/(.*)', 'index.php?pagename=discover/interiors/interior-results&tag1=$matches[1]', 'top' );
```